# How to simulate a "mailto:" call on Winforms Button Click?

Tags: winforms, email, button

I will send an email with a given address by open the standard email program like "mailto:" in an a-tag will do it, but within a button click.

How?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Example from [here](http://codegain.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=325)

```
private void btnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{ 
   string command = "mailto:info[at]codegain.com?subject=The Subject&bcc=vrrave[at]codegaim.com";  
   Process.Start(command); 
}
```

Comment: Additionally you can add body,cc, or/and bcc in the command:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737(v=vs.85).aspx

mailto:user@example.com?subject=Message Title&body=Message Content

Comment: codegain.com doesn't seem to exist any more. You might want to update or delete the link

Answer (score 12):

Here's how:

```
Process.Start("mailto:foo@bar.com");
```

Additionally, you can PInvoke into [ShellExecute](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.ShellExecute) to gain more control over this.